# Fastest way to match uri string

Tags: php, regex, indexing, uri

The following code is in the `index.php` file of my site and runs every time a page on my website is queried. Both of these `requires` execute there own respective `404` error pages so dont worry about that. What is the most performance efficient way of doing this within php?

```
$cache = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(preg_match('/^\/blog/',$cache) || preg_match('/^\/portfolio/',$cache)){
  define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
  // Loads the WordPress Environment and Template
  require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php'); 
}else{
  // Load codeigniter
  require('./codeigniter/index.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cache = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (0 === strpos($cache, '/blog/') ||
    0 === strpos($cache, '/portfolio/'))
{
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
    require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php'); 
}
    else
{
    require('./codeigniter/index.php');
}
```

No Regex needed and it is super fast.

Comment: The ending slashes were made for it not to match different uris beginning with blog or portfolio. I doubt that that can happen though lol
Thanks for picking my answer and none of the others.